# Pandas same columns for multiple IDs

Tags: python, pandas

I do not really know how to write my question understandable, that's why I give you this [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ONyR.png).

Basically I want to be able to access certain columns with same name under certain restrictions. So for example I want to be able to access the column 'A' with the ID 0 and J 0 or I want to access column 'C' with the ID 1 and J2.

Is there a Pandas function to get this result? Currently all my data is in multiple rows and there are two extra columns ID and J to differentiate columns like 'A', 'B' and 'C' from each other. This looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnOP7.png).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is a pivot table. Documentation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table).

Without any supplied data or code, its hard to give any more details than that.

Comment: Ah sry, https://github.com/FSaal/MoCap_Scitkit/blob/master/MotionCap_github.ipynb  as you can see all values for one column are displayed one after another, but I want all values for one joint and then all values for the next joint and so on.